# Amazon Cognito: user search as functionality in an App

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, api-design, amazon-cognito

I have read through the available AWS Cognito docs, but I am not sure if I understand how to best implement a "user search" feature: I want users to be able to search for each other and look at each other's user profiles.

Two specific requirements:

- Users are only able to search a subset of all users, given by a custom type.
- Users are able to search by a custom geo hash attribute

How to best approach this? I suppose I need a proxy API service as e.g. searching by custom attributes is not supported by AWS Cognito. But there are many questions:

- What AWS Api and authentication method should my proxy API use to connect to the AWS Cognito service?
- should the proxy API just try to use the sync feature of Cognito to maintain all users? Unnecessary risk?
- are the Cognito APIs SSL enabled by default so that the proxy API can connect safely?
- Should I use a proxy API at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito doesn't expose the attributes each user has publicly, so I'm not sure that approach will work directly. To achieve this end with what Cognito supports already, you would have to mirror the attributes stored against a user elsewhere, either by building your own hooks into update calls from the client or via Lambda. Potentially a bit cleaner is to only store those custom attributes that you need searched elsewhere and leveraging what Cognito supports whenever possible.

Update with more specific details, per request:

A rough outline that comes to mind:

1) Client side, once update attributes is called you build in a new hook that will update some remote data store (Elastisearch, Dynamo...etc.).

2) This data store should probably be backed by API gateway, using the Cognito access token as an authentication mechanism around it.

3) Another API to query this data store could be built in to API gateway as well, using the same authentication mechanism.

4) Queries would then go to this API and could be wrapped into whatever language or capabilities the storage has.

With this, it also allows you to build custom logic on who has access to what.

Comment: I agree: this is exactly what I described in my question as solution. Having a proxy API which stores users to allow searching. But can you say something about my questions how to best approach this? I proposed a further idea beyond having hooks or a lambda function to fill the proxy API: using the sync feature. What about that?

Comment: Right, I understand what you were proposing, I was just explaining an aspect you hadn't mentioned and were possibly overlooking. You could use Dynamo/several other services to mirror user attributes, use cognito federated identity to touch that directly, or, a bit more cleanly, API gateway to build a smarter API that will work with dynamo and use either federated identities or user pools directly to authenticate that call.

Comment: Thanks, you mention a lot oft good points here, but now it's a bit too condensed for me to follow everything. Could you modify your response and explain this in a bit more structured way, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Why people keep using a service that doesn't suit the needs of the industry is beyond me. Stop using AWS, it's garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I used a lambda function I created called listUsersLambda and the CognitoCredentialServiceProvider.listUsers function. and to my surprise it listed users but not the attributes that would help someone to determine who they are - like recognize emailId to choose suer to send notification to, but at least we can pick a congnito user by username etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not sure if I understand all of it though: you are suggesting to list all cognito users with "listUsers" and then filter the ones you actually want to return? Basically instead of having a proxy user search service, just have a proxy function that filters from all users on the fly? Biggest problem: "listUsers" cannot return more than 1000 users at once, so you would have to do many requests with a large user base.

Comment: I think using the lambda and admin functions is the way to go. But I think the whole system is troubling.